# How to remove specific character surrounding a string?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, trim

I have this string:

```
var str = "? this is a ? test ?";
```

Now I want to get this:

```
var newstr = "this is a ? test";
```

As you see I want to remove just those `?` surrounding *(in the beginning and end)* that string *(not in the middle of string)*. How can do that using JavaScript?

Here is what I have tried:

```js
var str = "? this is a ? test ?";
var result = str.trim("?");
document.write(result);
```

So, as you see it doesn't work. Actually I'm a PHP developer and [`trim()` works well in PHP](https://3v4l.org/o9KOB). Now I want to know if I can use `trim()` to do that in JS.

---

It should be noted [I can do that using regex](https://regex101.com/r/cY4sZ5/1), but to be honest I hate regex for this kind of jobs. Anyway is there any better solution?

---

**Edit:** As this mentioned in the comment, I need to remove both `?` and whitespaces which are around the string.

Comment: trim removes whitespace, this is not whitespace

Comment: I realise that now. Why not separate `0,1` and `length-1,length` into substrings and scan for the `?` (and remove whitespace), and then concatenate the strings back to the main string?

Comment: @Kyll I want to remove both  `?` and whitespaces which are around the string.

Comment: I think a bit overkill, but here would be the PHP trim function in js: http://phpjs.org/functions/trim/

Comment: @Rizier123 tnx for that link

Comment: On one hand you're saying you have a specific string to deal with, but on the other you don't explicitly state if that will be the exact format of the string. If it is, then the solution is simply `str.slice(2, -2)`. If not, then who knows what the solution is because you've not provided a detailed set of requirements.

Comment: @Shafizadeh Will your string have any amount of `?` at the beginning and end, or will it just be `? [text] ?`?

Comment: *"Anyway is there any better solution?"*: I don't think

Comment: What's your problem with regex? Why is the hatred..?

Comment: This is really unclear. What should be the output for `??? Test ?? ` or `Test ?? ??` or `? Test ?? ?` or some other combinations?

Comment: @Tunaki `?? Test ?` - `Test ?? ?` - `? Test ??`

Comment: Voted to reopen. I still can't get over how people are senior anything in the real world yet vote to close such an easy to comprehend programming question.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Search for character mask and return the rest without.

This proposal the use of the [bitwise not](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Bitwise_NOT) `~` operator for checking.

> `~` is a [bitwise not operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Bitwise_NOT). It is perfect for use with [`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf), because `indexOf` returns if found the index `0 ... n` and if not `-1`:
>
> ```
> value  ~value   boolean
>  -1  =>   0  =>  false
>   0  =>  -1  =>  true
>   1  =>  -2  =>  true
>   2  =>  -3  =>  true
>   and so on
> ```

```js
function trim(s, mask) {
    while (~mask.indexOf(s[0])) {
        s = s.slice(1);
    }
    while (~mask.indexOf(s[s.length - 1])) {
        s = s.slice(0, -1);
    }
    return s;
}

console.log(trim('??? this is a ? test ?', '? '));
console.log(trim('abc this is a ? test abc', 'cba '));
```

Comment: Nice, but it would be more efficient to work with two trim indexes and do `slice` once at the end.

Comment: @georg, it would need another test, if the indices overlap.

Comment: One question, What's the meaning of `~` in JS ?

Comment: @Shafizadeh, its a bitwise not operator, please see edit.

Comment: Please change the while to something like this: `while(s.length > 0 && ~mask.indexOf(s[0]))` to prevent from index out of bound exception

Comment: Also you maybe want to add whitespaces(space, \r, \n, \t) to mask at the top of the function to remove whitespaces so

Comment: @MostafaLavaei, javascript arrays returns `undefined` if out ouf bound. and `indexOf` of string with search for `undefined` returns `-1`, which is the expected non harmed value, no need to change something. the additional whitespace characters may easily added to the mask.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation

Comment: I'd up-vote this working answer *but* you voted to close a legitimate question and none of the other close-voters nor you bothered to edit a very easy to comprehend question to proper-English. I can't understand what you people are thinking and this lack of logic degrades Stack overall.

Answer (score 7):

Simply use:

```js
let text = '?? something ? really ??'
text = text.replace(/^([?]*)/g, '')
text = text.replace(/([?]*)$/g, '')

console.log(text)
```

Answer (score 6):

A possible solution would be to use recursive functions to remove the unwanted leading and trailing characters. This doesn't use regular expressions.

```
function ltrim(char, str) {
    if (str.slice(0, char.length) === char) {
        return ltrim(char, str.slice(char.length));
    } else {
        return str;
    }
}

function rtrim(char, str) {
    if (str.slice(str.length - char.length) === char) {
        return rtrim(char, str.slice(0, 0 - char.length));
    } else {
        return str;
    }
}
```

Of course this is only one of many possible solutions. The function `trim` would use both `ltrim` and `rtrim`.

The reason that `char` is the first argument and the string that needs to be cleaned the second, is to make it easier to change this into a functional programming style function, like so (ES 2015):

```
function ltrim(char) {
    (str) => {
        <body of function>
    }
}

// No need to specify str here
function ltrimSpaces = ltrim(' ');
```

Comment: PHP's trim function does also `trim("??string??", "??") // string.`

Comment: My aim has not been to create a function with the same behaviour as the php `trim` function, but I think I can add that feature.

Comment: @Xorifelse Interested to know how you'd be able to use PHP functions in JS efficiently without having to copy the PHP function (interested as I haven't done much JS, so it'll be interesting to know)?

Comment: @Xorifelse: updated my answer, it's now possible to trim multi-char strings.

Comment: @cybermonkey: if you don't want to copy the behaviour (and don't want to rely on a library that has done the work for you) of something that is present in php but not in javascript, you'll probably have to do (ajax) calls to a php script.

Comment: @Arjan Thought so, but wouldn't that slow down the page for the user?

Comment: @cybermonkey Absolutely. That's why it should be done on the client if at all possible. (And again on the server for data that needs to be stored somewhere, because data from any client must be considered insecure.)

Comment: @Arjan And now for the next one, by default (no args submitted) the trim function cuts automatically the following chars `'\n' (new line), '\r' (carriage return), '\t' (tab), '\v' (v-tab), '\0' (null)`

Comment: @Xorifelse it also trims spaces by default. Mine does not, nor is it required for the original question. So I'm not going to add it.

Comment: Also if you do not provide a **char** the error throws: _InternalError: too much recursion_
To fix this you may add `if (char.length && str.slice(...` in both functions.

Answer (score 4):

Here is one way to do it which checks for index-out-of-bounds and makes only a single call to `substring`:

```
String.prototype.trimChars = function(chars) {
  var l = 0;
  var r = this.length-1;
  while(chars.indexOf(this[l]) >= 0 && l < r) l++;
  while(chars.indexOf(this[r]) >= 0 && r >= l) r--;
  return this.substring(l, r+1);
};
```

Example:

```
var str = "? this is a ? test ?";

str.trimChars(" ?");  // "this is a ? test"
```

Answer (score 3):

Simple approach using `Array.indexOf`, `Array.lastIndexOf` and `Array.slice` functions:

**Update:** (note: the author has requested to trim the ***surrounding*** chars)

```
function trimChars(str, char){
    var str = str.trim();

    var checkCharCount = function(side) {
        var inner_str = (side == "left")? str : str.split("").reverse().join(""),
            count = 0;

        for (var i = 0, len = inner_str.length; i < len; i++) {
            if (inner_str[i] !== char) {
                break;
            }
            count++;
        }
        return (side == "left")? count : (-count - 1);
    };

    if (typeof char === "string" 
            && str.indexOf(char) === 0
            && str.lastIndexOf(char, -1) === 0) {
        str = str.slice(checkCharCount("left"), checkCharCount("right")).trim();
    }

    return str;
}

var str = "???? this is a ? test ??????";

console.log(trimChars(str, "?"));   // "this is a ? test"
```

Comment: No idea whether this answer is correct, but it's nice to see that someone's actually read the question (the previous four or five answers didn't and were deleted or/and downvoted).

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest maybe `str.slice(2, -2)` would be faster than `str.slice(1, -1).trim()`...?

Comment: @webeno, I don't think so, cause the initial string could be `"?a this is a ? test a?"`

Comment: @Shafizadeh, ok, I'll do it

Comment: @Shafizadeh: You think? Maybe you should just stop and decide exactly what you need before continuing. The question is far too vague and so it requires too many assumptions.

Comment: @squint I don't think the question is vague .. all I want is a `trim()` function which acts as `trim()` in PHP.

Comment: @Shafizadeh: Your question doesn't say you want PHP's `.trim()`; it only says that it works well. That doesn't mean you need a full replication. It could simply mean that whatever it is you want can be accomplished with PHP `.trim()`. But you *still haven't described exactly what you want*.

Comment: ...if it wasn't vague, you wouldn't be getting different answers based on different assumptions. As far as we know, if you have `"? ? foo ? bar ? ?"`, you may need to keep the second `?` in from each end. Should the result be `"foo ? bar"` or `"? foo ? bar ?"`?

Comment: @squint Yes you are right ... my question is vague ...! I want [this](https://3v4l.org/5Vcop) output for your example.

Comment: @Shafizadeh: But that retains the spaces as far as I can tell. (I don't know PHP, but... https://3v4l.org/ZfWAA )

Answer (score 3):

No regex:

```
uberTrim = s => s.length >= 2 && (s[0] === s[s.length - 1])?
  s.slice(1, -1).trim() 
  : s;
```

Step-by-step explanation:

1. Check if the string is at least 2 characters long and if it is surrounded by a specific character;
2. If it is, then first slice it to remove the surrounding characters then trim it to remove whitespaces;
3. If not just return it.

In case you're weirded out by that syntax, it's an [Arrow Function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Lexical_this) and a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).
The parenthesis are superfluous in the ternary by the way.

Example use:

```
uberTrim(''); // ''
uberTrim(' Plop! '); //'Plop!'
uberTrim('! ...What is Plop?!'); //'...What is Plop?'
```

Comment: @Shafizadeh Note that this code expects the amount of leading and trailing characters to always be two (one at each end). It won't trim `'!! Plop !!'` of all the `'!'` nor the whitespaces, resulting in `'! Plop !'`.

Answer (score 2):

to keep this question up to date using an ES6 approach:

I liked the bitwise method but when readability is a concern too then here's another approach.

```
function trimByChar(string, character) {
  const first = [...string].findIndex(char => char !== character);
  const last = [...string].reverse().findIndex(char => char !== character);
  return string.substring(first, string.length - last);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using regex

```
'? this is a ? test ?'.replace(/^[? ]*(.*?)[? ]*$/g, '$1')
```

You may hate regex but after finding a solution you will feel cool :)

Answer (score 1):

Javascript's trim method only remove whitespaces, and takes no parameters. For a custom trim, you will have to make your own function. Regex would make a quick solution for it, and you can find an implementation of a custom trim on [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_trim_string.asp) in case you don't want the trouble of going through the regex creation process. (you'd just have to adjust it to filter ? instead of whitespace

Answer (score -1):

This in one line of code which returns your desire output:

```
"? this is a ? test ?".slice(1).slice(0,-1).trim();
```